# Is there an Easier way to Get a 3 deep Panel Control from a Form in order to add a new Control to it programmatically?

Tags: c#, foreach, controls

I have a VB Windows Program Created by someone else, it was programmed so that anyone could Add to the functionality of the program through the use of Class Libraries, the Program calls them (ie... the Class Libraries, DLL files) Plugins, The Plugin I am creating is a C# Class Library. ie.. .dll

This specific Plugin Im working on Adds a Simple DateTime Clock Function in the form of a Label and inserts it into a Panel that is 3 Deep.  The Code I have I have tested and it works.  My Question is this:  Is there a better way to do it? for instance I use Controls.Find 3 different times, each time I know what Panel I am looking for and there will only be a single Panel added to the Control[] array.  So again Im doing a foreach on an array that only holds a single element 3 different times.

Now like I said the code works and does as I expected it to.  It just seems overly redudant, and Im wondering if there could be a performance issue.

here is the code:

```
    foreach (Control p0 in mDesigner.Controls)
        if (p0.Name == "Panel1")
        {
            Control panel1 = (Control)p0;
            Control[] controls = panel1.Controls.Find("Panel2", true);

            foreach (Control p1 in controls)
            if (p1.Name == "Panel2")
            {
                Control panel2 = (Control)p1;
                Control[] controls1 = panel2.Controls.Find("Panel3", true);
                foreach(Control p2 in controls1)
                    if (p2.Name == "Panel3")
                    {
                        Control panel3 = (Control)p2;
                        panel3.Controls.Add(clock);
                    }
             }
         }
```

Comment: Good question, but remember that unnecessary optimization is often a time waster!  It's pretty unlikely to affect performance if you're just looping through a few ui elements (even triple-nested).  Maybe if you had hundreds...

Answer (score 0):

Use the following function

```
   public static Control FindControlRecursive(Control control, string id)
    {
        if (control == null) return null;
        Control ctrl = control.FindControl(id);
        if (ctrl == null)
        {
            foreach (Control child in control.Controls)
            {
                ctrl = FindControlRecursive(child, id);
                if (ctrl != null) break;
            }
        }
        return ctrl;
    }
}
```

And then

```
Control panel3 = FindControlRecursive(mDesigner.Controls, "Panel3");
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply and I like the concept of your code, however your call to FindControlRecursive passes in mDesigner.Controls which is an Array but your FindControlRecursive Function takes a Control reference not an array, and also the Method control.FindControl is a System.Web.UI method whereas mDesigner.Controls contains System.Windows.Forms Controls. I guess I should have Mentioned that The Form I have is a Windows Form. Thanks for your reply...

Answer (score 0):

using the concept shared by Andrei I was able to work out a Method that not only works for just the Label that I wanted to add to a Panel but it also allows me to call it from another method that simply modifies the size and location of two other Controls, making this function very reuseable.

```
private Control FindControlRecursive(Control ct, string id)
{
    Control[] c;
    Control ctr;

    if (ct == null)
        c = mDesigner.Controls.Find(id, true);
    else
        c = ct.Controls.Find(id, true);

    foreach (Control child in c)
    {
        if (child.Name == id)
        {
            ctr = child;
            return ctr;
        }
        else
        {
            ctr = FindControlRecursive(child, id);
            if (ctr != null)
                return ctr;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

The Calling Code looks like this:

```
Control ct = null;
Control panel3 = FindControlRecursive(ct, "Panel3");

// and Here is where I can Add controls or even change control properties.
if (panel3 != null)
    panel3.Controls.Add(clock);
```

Thanks for the help...